# Find host name used to connect to my socket server

Tags: python, sockets

I am using Python SocketServer to implement a socket server.

How can I find out if client used `example.com` to connect to me, or used `x.x.x.x`?

Actually, I need something like virtual hosts in Apache.

Googling didn't come up with any notable result.

Thanks

Comment: virtual hosts in Apache works because it is specified in the HTTP RFC to send the host header.  Unless your client similarly sends the name it used to connect, there is really no way to find this out.  DNS lookup happens separately and resolves a host name to an IP.  The IP is then used to connect.

Comment: do u mean to ask if you want to know if user connected to you through domain name or ip

Comment: @Sar009 Yes, that is my question.

Comment: I suppose it cant be done because when a user uses domain name, it is resolved for the IP and then IP is used to connect to the server.

Comment: I was afraid so. Then this is impossible. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

virtual hosts in Apache works because it is specified in the HTTP RFC to send the host header. Unless your client similarly sends the name it used to connect, there is really no way to find this out. DNS lookup happens separately and resolves a host name to an IP. The IP is then used to connect. –  Kinjal Dixit